# Unable to run commands in azure, either with Set-AzVMRunCommand or az vm run-command create

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to run a script using either PowerShell AZ or AZ Cli.
The script is located in an Azure Blob Storage, it is supposed to download a zip file on the server, unzip it and launch the installation.
The URL if the Zip file is provided as parameter of the script (this url contains a SAS token).

Everything works perfectly fine when using the "Run Command" blade of Azure Web Portal.

I now want to industrialize the actions a little bit better with a script that creates a SAS token and pass the parameters directly to initiate run commands.

I initially tried with Set-AzVMRunCommand, but had an issue to pass parameters: whatever the syntax used, the parameter value is never passed.
The best I could achieve was to pass -Parameter @{name="URL";value="$ZipURI"} where I can see the "URL" parameter with Get-AzVMRunCommand but the value seems to never arrive.

I then tried with az cli as it seemed to solve the problem for many, but it does not look like az cli understands the --script-uri when it contains a SAS token, as I get errors like that:

> 'se' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

Edit:
Many thanks for your answers.
Here are the full commands, I hope that helps, do not hesitate to ask me for more details.

```
Set-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VMName $VirtualMachineName -RunCommandName "Deploy" -SourceScriptUri $SourceScriptURI -Location $Location -Parameter $Parameters
```

$SourceScriptURI is an url generated with the script name and SAS token
$Parameters = @{name="URL";value="$ZipURI"}

Command is similar in AZ Cli

```
az vm run-command create --run-command-name "TaniumInstall" --vm-name $VirtualMachineName --resource-group $ResourceGroupName --script-uri $SourceScriptURI -protected-parameters URL=$ZipURI
```

Has anyone ever achieved this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the full commands you’re trying to execute in your question? (Add them to your original post, and not as comments please)

Comment: Hi, added in the edit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I initially tried with Set-AzVMRunCommand, but had an issue to pass parameters: whatever the syntax used, the parameter value is never passed. The best I could achieve was to pass -Parameter @{name="URL";value="$ZipURI"} where I can see the "URL" parameter with Get-AzVMRunCommand but the value seems to never arrive

To run the [AzVMRunCommand Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest) command with parameter values and execute the script in a `VM`.

1. Upload the `powershell` script in `VM`

> Note: The script path parameter will only accept a path inside the **VM**, not a blob path.

**Sample.ps1**

```
    param (
        [string] $arg1
    )
    $folder = New-Item C:\Folder11\venkatscript.txt -Type File
    $outputMessage = "This is a sample script with parameters $arg1" 
    $outputMessage += "File has been created in VM Path $folder"
    Write-Output $outputMessage
```

2. Execute the below command.

```
 az vm run-command invoke  --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name "Venkat" -g "Sri" --scripts "C:\Folder11\sample.ps1  Venkat"
```

**Output:**

[image]

Pass the value you want to pass an argument.

When I check in the `VM`, the script is executed, and the folder is also created.

[image]

Reference: [Executing Powershell script on Remote VM on Azure with Parameters - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75326154/executing-powershell-script-on-remote-vm-on-azure-with-parameters/75331629#75331629)

Comment: Hi, I use -SourceScriptUri for PowerShellAZ or --script-uri for az CLI, which both are documented as parameters to pass a script in a blob storage.

Comment: Microsoft --parameters argument is not working, same is already verified. Refer same parameter Qns in [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75326154/executing-powershell-script-on-remote-vm-on-azure-with-parameters/75331629#75331629)